# How to use a static variable to hold state within a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I've written the following toy function to see how the stack grows downwards on recursive function calls and then unwinds on returns:

```
void countdown(int n) {

    // trying to get initial address so the math is a bit simpler 
    // on how much the stack grows down/up
    static intptr_t initial_address = (intptr_t) &n;

    if (n!=0) {
        printf("%d...at address: %p\n", n, &n);
        countdown(n-1);
        printf("%d...at address: %p\n", n, &n);
    } else 
        printf("Liftoff!\n");
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this without passing another argument to the `countdown` function? If so, what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: ...or you could just pass another argument to the countdown function, eg. a pointer to a state struct.

Comment: @MartinJames so for the above you'd just add in another arg, such as `void count(int n, State *state) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `max` value of the address-of or previous address-of, knowing that the top-level function call will have the highest stack address. For example:

```
void countdown(int n) {

    // will only be initialized once, and first value is throw-away, since
    // the memory address is always going to be greater than zero
    static intptr_t initial_address=0;

    if (n!=0)
    {

        initial_address = initial_address > (intptr_t) &n ? initial_address : (intptr_t) &n;

        // pushing upto the stack (will grow down...)
        printf("%d...at address %p | offset: -%#zx\n", n, &n, initial_address - (intptr_t) &n); 
        countdown(n-1);

        // stack unwinds after function starts returning
        printf("%d...at address %p | offset: -%#zx\n", n, &n, initial_address - (intptr_t) &n); // pushing upto the stack (will grow down...)
    }
    else 
        printf("Liftoff!\n");
}
```

> 4...at address 0x7ffe6944967c | offset: -0 
> 3...at address 0x7ffe6944965c | offset: -0x20 
> 2...at address 0x7ffe6944963c | offset: -0x40
> 1...at address 0x7ffe6944961c | offset: -0x60
> Liftoff!
> 1...at address 0x7ffe6944961c | offset: -0x60
> 2...at address 0x7ffe6944963c | offset: -0x40
> 3...at address 0x7ffe6944965c | offset: -0x20
> 4...at address 0x7ffe6944967c | offset: -0